# Does showcasing pet projects on my personal blog compensate for not having references?

Tags: graduate-admissions

If you have been working on projects independently and not under a professor, does compiling your work on a personal website/blog also serve as a good reference for an admission committee looking to select a graduate student for a Master of Science program? Or should a professor always vouch for the work you do? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, realistically a list of external projects will *not* make up for not having letters.**

Letters are typically not, or not primarily, used as a description of projects you have done, but as a subjective evaluation of your potential as a <strike>PhD</strike> graduate student. Letters *may* include a discussion of undergraduate research, but will also include a discussion of your personality, especially your strengths and weaknesses as a researcher. It is evident that this cannot be learned from a description of projects alone, especially given that this list is curated by yourself.

Incidentally, this is also the reason why senior professors are considered the "best" references - admission committees assume that the best judge of prospective grad students are those you have seen many grad students succeed and fail, i.e., senior professors.

**Edit:** as jvb correctly notes, the question is about master rather than PhD applications, but at least for a master by research, this does not change the spirit of my answer. For masters by coursework, I think most universities don't really employ a competitive selection procedure anyway (at least the ones I know don't).

Comment: Please reconsider the question asked, it's not about PhD students.

Comment: Even a not very selective program would probably be skittish about someone with *no* references.  It's hard to think of a bigger red flag.

Answer (score -1):

Depends :) If your pet project is `gcc` or some part of the Linux kernel (to give a computer science example), or something else which is well-known and actually in use somewhere, or a successful commercial product, it might serve this purpose well. And of course it's interesting to get to know the candidate a little bit.

On the other hand, I wouldn't be overly impressed by most *un-reviewed* work. (Incidentally, this includes work of professors and workgroups, too.)

Comment: I think this answer is (very) misleading. Even a very good "pet project" does not serve the purpose that letters serve, i.e., evaluating your potential as a PhD candidate.

Comment: @xLeitix but the question was **not** about evaluating potential as a PhD candidate, but for a master's degree course. In the end, the result of the masters degree will show the potential for a PhD.